# MYSQL Select with count, sum, inner join and group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

```
SELECT COUNT(s.fid) AS tcount, SUM(t.size) AS tsize, s.uid 
FROM xbt_files_users AS s INNER JOIN torrents AS t 
ON s.fid = t.id 
WHERE s.active = 1 AND s.mtime > '.$time.' AND s.remaining = 0 AND t.size >= 52428800 
GROUP BY s.uid
```

I have some problems with this query, in busy, some times takes more than 20 seconds ...
xbt_files_users is having index for: ARM(active, remaining, mtime), uid, (fid/uid - unique)
torrents is having index for size, id primary
It`s using:

> Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort for xbt_files_users

and

> Using where for torrents

It's any way to improve this query?

Comment: To help you better, can you please show us your show create table output? ie.  `SHOW CREATE TABLE xbt_files_users;` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE torrents ;` and also the execution plan for the query `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT .. your query goes here...` by generally, creating an index on xbt_files_users(fid, active, remaining, mtime) and another on torrents(id,size) will help you assuming that the id and the fid types are identical

Comment: Agree with Mike... your torrents table should be indexed on (ID, SIZE) to match the join first, then the size criteria... don't start with size first, then ID.

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT COUNT(s.fid) AS tcount, SUM(t.size) AS tsize, s.uid 
FROM xbt_files_users s INNER JOIN
     torrents t 
     ON s.fid = t.id 
WHERE s.active = 1 AND s.mtime > '.$time.' AND s.remaining = 0 AND t.size >= 52428800 
GROUP BY s.uid
```

The best indexes for these queries are `xbt_files_users(active, remaining, mtime, fid, uid)` and `torrents(id, size)`.  I would start with those indexes.

Comment: On the xbt table the best index will be what you stated but without the uid as that is not a valid column. Also the fid will have to be the first column otherwise the index may not be used.

Comment: @Mike . . . The `select` has `s.uid`, so I don't know why you think it would not be valid column.  As for the ordering of the columns, that is quite intentional, so the `where` filters are first in the index followed by the columns used for the join and then the select.